# Practical use (and reuse) of the CONSTRUCT clause

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantics, triplestore

When using `CONSTRUCT` in a sparql query, the output is a [single RDF graph](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#construct), aka a set of triples, which essentially *new* data. But in general, I've considered `CONSTRUCT` to be a way of manually creating a rule that in theory should be reusable.

---

In an example usage of `CONSTRUCT`, let's say I wanted to define something that wasn't already in the data. [Here's a good example taken from an article about CONSTRUCT](http://www.snee.com/bobdc.blog/2009/09/appreciating-sparql-construct.html).

```
@prefix : <http://some.site.com/ont#> .

:jane :hasParent :gene .
:gene :hasParent :pat ;
      :gender    :female .
:joan :hasParent :pat ;
      :gender    :female . 
:pat  :gender    :male .
:mike :hasParent :joan .
```

"The following CONSTRUCT statement creates new triples based on the ones above to specify who is who's grandfather:"

```
PREFIX : <http://some.site.com/ont#>

CONSTRUCT { ?p :hasGrandfather ?g . }
WHERE {?p      :hasParent ?parent .
       ?parent :hasParent ?g .
       ?g      :gender    :male .
}
```

and the result:

```
@prefix :        <http://some.site.com/ont#> .
:jane    :hasGrandfather    :pat .
:mike    :hasGrandfather    :pat .
```

---

Once I've generated the *new triples* as a result of `CONSTRUCT` queries, does that mean I have to take that data, and input it back into the database in order to start using/reusing `:hasGrandfather`? or can I reference the resulting RDF graph as if I would reference a dynamic table in SQL?

Are there other useful ways to interact with the triples that are generated as a result of using `CONSTRUCT`?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using SPARQL 1.1, and you're querying against a triplestore, you'd typically use INSERT to add those triples to the store (to the same graph or to a different graph).  Have a look at section 3.1 from [SPARQL 1.1 Update](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/):

> #### [3.1 Graph Update](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-update-20130321/#graphUpdate)
>
> Graph update operations change existing graphs in the Graph Store but
>   do not explicitly delete nor create them. Non-empty inserts into
>   non-existing graphs will, however, implicitly create those graphs,
>   i.e., an implementation fulfilling an update request should silently
>   an automatically create graphs that do not exist before triples are
>   inserted into them, and must return with failure if it fails to do so
>   for any reason. (For example, the implementation may have insufficient
>   resources, or an implementation may only provide an update service
>   over a fixed set of graphs and the implicitly created graph is not
>   within this fixed set). An implementation may remove graphs that are
>   left empty after triples are removed from them.
>
> SPARQL 1.1 Update provides these graph update operations: …
>
> - The fundamental pattern-based actions for graph updates are INSERT and DELETE (which can co-occur in a single DELETE/INSERT operation).
>     These actions consist of groups of triples to be deleted and groups of
>     triples to be added. The specification of the triples is based on
>     query patterns. The difference between INSERT / DELETE and INSERT DATA
>     / DELETE DATA is that INSERT DATA and DELETE DATA do not substitute
>     bindings into a template from a pattern. The DATA forms require
>     concrete data (triple templates containing variables within DELETE
>     DATA and INSERT DATA operations are disallowed and blank nodes are
>     disallowed within DELETE DATA, see Notes 8+9 in the grammar).  Having
>     specific operations for concrete data means that a request can be
>     streamed so that large, pure-data updates can be done.

Later in the same document:

> #### Example 8:
>
> This example copies triples from one named graph to another named
>   graph based on a pattern:
>
> ```
> PREFIX dc:  <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
> PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
>
> INSERT 
>   { GRAPH <http://example/bookStore2> { ?book ?p ?v } }
> WHERE
>   { GRAPH  <http://example/bookStore>
>        { ?book dc:date ?date .
>          FILTER ( ?date > "1970-01-01T00:00:00-02:00"^^xsd:dateTime )
>          ?book ?p ?v
>   } }
> ```

Comment: 1. When you say it is *typical* to insert those into the store, does that mean that is the only way to use them? 2. in example 8, would the whole `CONSTRUCT`/`WHERE` query be included within the scope of `GRAPH <uri> { #here }`?

Comment: "Once I've generated the new triples as a result of CONSTRUCT queries, does that mean I have to take that data, and input it back into the database in order to start using/reusing :hasGrandfather?"  If you wanted to query the constructed triples, you'd need to put them somewhere that you could query.  Adding them back to the same or a different named graph would be a way to do that.  I think INSERT is probably typical there.

Comment: That example highlights the use of named graphs.  It's querying one graph `<http://example/bookStore>`, and constructing some triples and storing them in a different graph, `<http://example/bookStore2>`.  You could, of course, store them in the same graph, or in the default graph, too.  The example is just highlighting some options.  It's probably worth the time to give a quick read through those sections of the documentation;  you don't need to memorize all the details right away, but you'll have an idea what you can do, and you'll know whether to look for the details when you need them.

Answer (score 2):

To supplement Joshua's answer, since you seem to be using construct queries to write rules, you might consider using, or at least looking at, OWL and using a database which supports reasoning (there are several).  Some databases which support OWL will also support SWRL rules, so you could use both.

If you want to stick with rules, but prefer SPARQL, Stardog has a [SPARQL based syntax for SWRL](http://docs.stardog.com/owl2/); they're still SWRL rules, but with a palatable syntax.  There's also [SPIN](http://spinrdf.org/), which while not a standard, is SPARQL-based and like rules, but is not a formal standard.

Comment: for me, that begs another question: what else can `CONSTRUCT` be used for?

Comment: I think it's good for extracting a specific subgraph from a dataset

Comment: and that resulting subgraph would then be inserted into your database for later use?

Comment: Does not need to be.  As Joshua set, SPARQL Update is more appropriate for adding data to your database by SPARQL.  Construct can simply be used to extract an interesting/useful subgraph that your application might need to perform some logic over.